# Laravel: Check if time + 4 hours has passed

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I store in my database a date format like this:

```
2017-02-22 16:55:40
```

I added it to my database like this:

```
Carbon::now();
```

I need to check if 4 hours passed since this date.

How I can do this? I couldn't figure out how I can convert this format into Carbon or timestamp.

Comment: Is this date tied to a model ?

Comment: The date added manually

Comment: Ok but it's related to an entity right? Just add the date field as a date in `$dates` array of the specific model and you can use carbon automatically

Comment: Thansk @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it to a Carbon object with:

```
Carbon::parse('2017-02-22 16:55:40');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Laravel and the date is a Carbon instance from a Model you have access to the whole Carbon API.

You can use the [Difference API](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) of Carbon for this specific purpose.

```
echo $model->thedate->diffInHours($now, false);
```

If your model does not threat the date as a carbon instance you can *cast* it by adding the date to the dates array of the current model like so

```
 protected $dates = [
    'field_name',
];
```

Check out [Date casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) for more information

**Update** with an explicit example

```
$user = User::first();
// This will return the difference in hours 
$user->created_at->diffInHours(Carbon\Carbon::now(), false);
```